# angular carousel indicator not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-carousel

I am using [angular-carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel) to display set of images in a carousel. The carousel is working fine except the indicator.The indicator are not getting displayed. Following is the code for carouse.

```
  <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-pause-on-hover="" rn-carousel-auto-slide="" class="image" ng-init="images = ['assets/img/1.png','assets/img/2.png','assets/img/3.png']">
    <li ng-repeat="image in images"><img src="{{image}}"/></li>
  </ul>
```

The following is the div to display the indicator.

```
<div rn-carousel-indicators ng-if="images.length > 1" slides="images" rn-carousel-index="carouselIndex"></div>
```

Can anybody suggest how to get the indicator working.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `carouselIndex` to the carousel directive:

```
<ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-pause-on-hover="" rn-carousel-auto-slide="" rn-carousel-index="carouselIndex" class="image" ng-init="images = ['assets/img/1.png','assets/img/2.png','assets/img/3.png']">
```

Comment: indicator are not even visible

Comment: From the documentation: _Note: If loading in slides from an async service, the ng-if="slides.length > 1" may not update as expected. In this case, try ng-if="slides"._ - So if that's the case, try change to indicator directive's `nfIf` to `ng-if="images"`

Comment: see the console output after updating to `ng-if="images"` and keeping `ng-if="images.lenght>1"`

Comment: Try setting the images inside the controller, I'm not sure why it's not working, so i'll remove this answer

Comment: The `images` were not in the scope of indicator `<div>`. I moved the `images` initialization on the parent of `<ul>`. Now the indicator are displayed but not working as per sliding or on click.

Comment: Try changing (both in the carousel directive and indicators directives) `carouselIndex` to `carousel.carouselIndex` (Make the index an object - It might help)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100855/discussion-between-ajeet-khan-and-alon).